# Excel - Reference cells with same value and SUM

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The excel data sheet I have takes this form:

```
XGTI, 10
XGTI, 12
BIOC, 5
BIOC, 5
BIOC, 1
BIOC, 10
XGTI, 5
BIOC, 1
MGT, 2
MGT, 4
```

I would like to total all the values separately from each other.
e.g.

```
XGTI = 27
BIOC = 22
MGT = 6
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: I think you're looking for `SUMIF` or maybe even a pivot table but that might be overkill. Try it out and come back if you can't get it.

Comment: You want SUMIF()/SUMIFS()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is in column A (XGTI,BIOC,...) in column B (10,12...) copy column A to another column E for example and remove duplicates(Data Tab, Remove Duplicates) you will have one XGTI, one BIOC... in F1 write the following:
**=SUMIF($A$1:$A$10,E1,$B$1:$B$10)**

Where A1:A10 is the column of XGTI,... and $ for absolute reference to let you drag the formula.
B1:B10 is the column of corresponding numbers 10,...   ($ for absolute reference to let you drag the formula.)

E1 is your first data to calculate the Sum for (where you removed duplicates)
and you can drag the formula down to have all totals